# Schema name with dash/hyphen i HyperSQL

Tags: java, testing, hsqldb

I'm writing unittests for a legacy application that uses mysql directly as a datastorage.

The approach we have descided on is to abstract out the database access to it's own layer, and dependency inject that. We will also write tests for that layer using hsqldb as a in memory database (for speed reasons).

The current code use a schema that has a dash in it's name, and as far as i can figure out hypersql doesn't have any way to escape that?

Do I need to inject the schema name into the database layer, or is there some way to configure hsqldb to accept dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your database access code is using something like `SELECT * FROM schema-name.tablename`, or `SCHEMA-NAME.tablename` with any character case variations, then you should use this with HyperSQL:

```
CREATE SCHEMA "SCHEMA-NAME" AUTHORIZATION DBA

and

SELECT * FROM "SCHEMA-NAME".tablename
```

If all your data is in the same schema, then you can simply set this schema as default and avoid using "SCHEMA-NAME" in SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, we need to do some cross schema queries, so this might be a good solution, I'll experiment a bit here.